# Selenium webdriver script that runs in IE hangs in Firefox

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have used selenium RC in the past but I am new to webdriver.
 I have three links in my app. Notifications, messages and connections.
On clicking notifications, notifications drop box is displayed. On clicking messages, messages drop box is displayed and on clicking connections, connections drop box is displayed.
In the script, I click notifications link, wait for notifications drop box and then assert for notifications dropbox. Same for messages and connections in sequence.
The notification sequence works correctly. In messages, it clicks on messages link and then hangs on the wait for messages drop box link. I know this since I had put print command after every line.
Heres is my code:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='notifications-page-button']")).sendKeys("\n");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='notifications-dropdown-list']//li//div[@class='message']")));
Assert.assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.xpath("//div[@id='notifications-dropdown-list']//li//div[@class='message']")), "Notifications drop box was not displayed");

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@id='messages-page-button']")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='messages-page-button']")).sendKeys("\n");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='sf_messages_list dropdown']//li//div[@class='message']"))); //This is the line where the script hangs. If I remove this line and the next line and continue with just the click commands, they work. But when I have this line and the next, the remaining click commands are not executed

Assert.assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.xpath("//div[@class='sf_messages_list dropdown']//li//div[@class='message']")), "Messages drop box was not displayed");

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("connections-page-button"))); 
driver.findElement(By.id("connections-page-button")).click()
```

Heres the HTML for messages section:

```
<li class="icon mm open">
<a id="messages-page-button" class="mm" href="#">
<span class="icon"></span>
<span class="badge hidden_elem">
<strong>
<em>0</em>
</strong>
</span>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-holder">
<div class="sf_messages_list dropdown" data-eventprefix="mainmenu_messages">
<div class="tb-dropdown-header">Messages</div>
<div class="tb-dropdown-body" data-url="/messages/dropdown">
<div class="document-title" style="display: none; !important"> - Dropdown Messages</div>
<div id="messages_list_view_76345" class="message-threads-listview">
<ul>
<div class="no_items hidden_elem">
</div>
</div>
<div class="tb-dropdown-footer" style="display: block;">
</div>
<span class="shadow-hide"></span>
</div>
</li>
```

Heres the HTML for notifications section:

```
<li class="icon mm">
<a id="notifications-page-button" class="mm" href="#">
<span class="icon"></span>
<span class="badge hidden_elem">
<strong>
<em>0</em>
</strong>
</span>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-holder">
<div id="notifications-dropdown-list" class="sf_notifications_list dropdown" data-eventprefix="mainmenu_notifications">
<div class="tb-dropdown-header">Notifications</div>
<div class="tb-dropdown-body" data-url="/notifications/dropdown"></div>
<div class="tb-dropdown-footer">
<a class="view_all" href="/notifications/view">View All Notifications</a>
</div>
</div>
<span class="shadow-hide"></span>
</div>
</li>
```

The above code works on IE. So looks like the problem is not that it is not able to find the element.
I am using Selenium 2.25.0. I have tried various versions of FF including 3.6, 7, 11, 13, 15 and 16. But none of them worked.
Also, the script just hangs. It does not even throw an error in eclipse. I had once let my script run for around 11 hours and still no error.

Please let me know in case you need further information to help me resolve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Going through exactly the same situation of yours. Not able to figure out what to do.. Did u solve this? or is there a work around? Please help me....! :-(

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me in previous versions of Selenium Webdriver. And I was also clueless, whats happening to me. Eventually, updating to newest version of Selenium helped me for good, but because 2.25.0 is the latest, I will at least present you the workaround I was using until update solved it

Whenever I needed to click a button, nothing happened (as to you). So the workaround was, that when clicking button, I also send `Enter` key event to it.

To be more specific:

```
 WebElement buttonWhereClickingDoesNotWork = driver.findElement(By.id("messages-page-button");
buttonWhereClickingDoesNotWork.click();
buttonWhereClickingDoesNotWork.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Yes, its workaround. Yes, its not nice. And yes, it did help me.

And also: No, I do not know the root cause of this, since update of Selenium helped me in my case...

Comment: Thanks for your response. Atleast there is someone who has faced this and can understand my situation :). I tried the workaround you suggested but it did not help. I added the commands to press enter after click command. But I am using Selenium 2.25.0 and FF 15. DO you think I should use Selenium 2.22 with FF 13 or previous for your workaround to work?

Comment: I tried downgrading to Selenium 2.22 and FF 13. Tried the workaround that you suggested but it did not work :(

Comment: Too bad ... that was the only workaround I know and it was working to me

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have some connection with a Facebook Login. Are you correctly switching between window handles? Also what is your implicit time out, by default it is set at 30 seconds, so I am not sure if your script can run for 11 hours without erroring out.

Can you try these

1) I am *guessing*, `className("message")` does not exist, and your script is actually getting stuck at that step and not the step after. Which involves the click.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("notifications-page-button")).click();
wait.until(driver.findElement(By.id("messages-page-button")));#<<-- Changed the element to wait for

//The code works untill here. But on the next command that clicks messages link, it hangs
driver.findElement(By.id("messages-page-button")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className(("username"))));
```

2) Remove that wait for element

```
driver.findElement(By.id("notifications-page-button")).click();
#removed this wait for element

//The code works untill here. But on the next command that clicks messages link, it hangs
driver.findElement(By.id("messages-page-button")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className(("username"))));
```

**UPDATE**

---

Please try this ...

```
driver.findElement(By.id("notifications-page-button")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className(("message"))));

//The code works untill here. But on the next command that clicks messages link, it hangs
driver.findElement(By.id("messages-page-button")).click();
wait.until(driver.findElement(By.id("connections-page-button"))); # changed it to wait for the element that you will next work with

driver.findElement(By.id("connections-page-button")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className(("connections-listview"))));
```

Also, if your provide an HTML snippet of the web elements, which you are not sure abt the locator, we can help figure it out.

Comment: Yes. The switching happens correctly. It even executes the first click command on the main window after logging in. But after that, does nothing. If the implicit wait is 30 seconds then that should be it. Also, the wait parameter that I have specified is 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I tried both your suggestions and it did not work :(

Comment: No problem, can you put in some print commands to confirm the step your actually getting stuck at and update the question

Comment: It gets stuck at the point where it is trying to click the messages button.I modified the code as:                    `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='notifications-page-button']")).click();
System.out.print("Notification button click passed");                                     
driver.findElement(By.id("messages-page-button")).click();
System.out.print("Message button click passed");`
In the console I see: Notification button click passed.

Comment: That seemed to have helped!!! But the problem is, if I wait for message element and then add Thread.sleep the script does not click on the message element. For example `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='notifications-page-button']")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@id='messages-page-button']"))); Thread.sleep(2000); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='messages-page-button']")).click();`This code does not work. But when I remove sleep, it works.So I think its expecting me to click on the element that I was waiting for right away.

Comment: I don't need it really. But I need to add some asserts. Will try it out and let you know again if it works :)